# 6s atmospheric correction for hyper spectral data

Tags: atmospheric-correction, hyperspectral-sensor

I am trying to customize atmospheric correction for hyper-spectral data. Presently for Landsat I am using the i.atcorr GRASS GIS module. I want to know whether 6S atmospheric correction can be used for hyper spectral data or 6sv1 (vector version) only has to be used for Hyper-spectral data?

Comment: There are other methods for atmospheric correction for hyperspectral data such as QUAC and FLAASH. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7456604/

Comment: I need an opensource one. the above mentioned software may be required license to be taken.I also tried to build and use 6SV1 using Conda python interface.but its not working on 64bit platform

Comment: Py6s should get you started. https://py6s.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html